# Moving a div to an already existing list

Tags: jquery

I have my searchbox code in a div. I need to move this to my toggle navigation that has list items. I could successfully move my div using this:

```
 $('.nav ul').prepend($('#search').html());
```

But now I need to make this div appear as a list item. How do I do that?

This is what my navigation looks like:

```
<nav class="nav">

    <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

Is this something doable?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you post what are you trying to do and a fiddle if possible

Comment: It's important to note that you cannot move any another element into `<ul>` except for `<li>`, so if #search is not a list item you will have to wrap it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) you `#search` div in a list item after moving it :

```
$('#search').prependTo('.nav ul').wrap('<li />');
```

([JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/LJUPL/1/))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can this be modified to include class nav-item, for this list-item too?

Comment: `$('#search').prependTo('.nav ul').wrap('<li class="nav-item" />');`

Comment: This actually moved my search bar to mobile navigation for mobile breakpoint, but when I resize my browser back to tablet and above, my original searchbar is gone(which was copied to move). How can I make it reappear on browser resize to its original position and make it appear in mobile navigation too?

Comment: You need two distinct search bar in this case. One would be displayed on mobiles only, the other one on tablet/desktop. The mobile search bar would have `visible-xs` class, and the other one `hidden-xs` ([see here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities))

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav ul').prepend($('<li>'+$('#search').html()+'</li>'));
```